# UIAlertViewDelegate in separate class

Tags: ios, swift

Im defining a class that conforms to the UIAlertViewDelegate as such:

```
class PaymentAlert: NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    var orderId: Int!
    var items: [String]

    init(orderId: Int, items: [String]) {
        self.orderId = orderId
        self.items = items
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println(index)
    }

}
```

I then in another class do these actions:

```
var alertClass = PaymentAlert(orderId: orderId, items: items)

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Payment declined", message: "Do you want to retry?", delegate: alertClass, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Retry")

                alert.show()
```

Everything runs fine except, the clickedButtonIndex delegate function never gets called when i click any button, i tried to set the delegate to alertClass.self which didn't do much.

Why is it that the clickedButtonIndex function never gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAlertView`'s `delegate` property is `weak` and thus your `PaymentAlert` instance is destroyed before you tapped the button.

You have to keep a strong reference to the `PaymentAlert` instance somewhere until the alert was dismissed.

Comment: Do you have any examples of keeping a strong reference?

Comment: The construct you're trying to build is not that simple to do. If you're creating the `UIAlertView` inside a `UIViewController` you should store the `PaymentAlert` in a variable there. ---- You could also subclass `PaymentAlert` from `UIAlertView` and setting itself as `delegate`. ---- But in general it's not a good practice to have a separate alert class to be your delegate. The object which displays the alert view should also be the delegate to have a consistent lifecycle.